# Como determinar cuantas veces se repite cierto item dentro de una lista?

Tags: python, lista

En una determinada lista quiero buscar aquellos items que sean iguales para contarlos.

Actualmente hasta este código llegue, intente crear un contador para los items pero no lo he logrado:.

```
def lista_nombres():
    nombres = []
    while True:
        x = input("Ingresa un nombre o 0 para terminar: ")
        if x == "0":
            break
        if x in nombres:
            continue           
        nombres.append(x)
    return nombres

nombres = lista_nombres()
print("La lista es:", nombres)
```

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias usar el módulo `Counter`, te proporciona la información que necesitas, aqui está una manera de hacerlo:

```
from collections import Counter

def nombres():
  ns = []
  while True:
    inp = input('Ingresa un nombre o 0 para terminar: ').strip().capitalize()
    if inp == '0':
      return nombres
    else:
      ns.append(inp)

print(Counter(nombres()))
```